# Copy a prebuild file to build folder (SCons)

Tags: scons

I want to copy a (prebuild) file from the source folder to the destination folder (variant_dir).

This results in a dependency cycle:

```
Command('main.elf', 'main.elf', Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))
```

How could I specify that the file to copy is located in the source folder (project folder) and the target is in the build folder without using constant values (in SConscript)?

As workaround I renamed the file:

```
Command('main.elf', 'main.orig', Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))
```

Comment: Are you using duplicate=0 with variant dir?

Comment: yes, duplicate=False

Comment: Did you try my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the proper syntax for what you want to do:

```
Command('main.elf', 'main.elf', Copy("$TARGET", "${SOURCE.srcpath}"))
```

See: http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html and search for srcpath to see the section on substitution.

That said what you are really asking for is duplicate=partial. I'm not sure if this will work.

Can you specify the elf file with full path on the command line to your tool?

```
Command('main.elf', 'main.elf',"my_tool $TARGET ${SOURCE.srcpath}")
```

Or equivalent?

Comment: a) `srcpath` seems to have no effect: scons: *** Found dependency cycle(s): variant_dir/main.elf -> variant_dir/main.elf. b) I didn't find anything about _partial_ mode in the docs (only 0 and 1 for `duplicate`). c) I don't want to use the full path for all subsequent tools.

Comment: To be clear when I said you are asking for duplicate=partial I didn't mean it existed, but that was the functionality you wanted.